# Why number of splits are different for the same Hadoop example for Java example vs Hadoop streaming with python example from Definitive Guide

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hadoop-streaming

I am executing maximum temperature example from chapter 2 of Hadoop Definitive Guide and I noticed that number of splits for Java example is different over Hadoop Streaming with Python. Can someone help me understand the reasoning behind this difference ?

Output for Java example:

```
Job Counters 
                Launched map tasks=1
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Rack-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=7007
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=5760
                Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=7007
                Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=5760
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=7007
                Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=5760
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=7175168
                Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=5898240
```

Output for Hadoop streaming with Python example:

```
Job Counters 
        Launched map tasks=2
        Launched reduce tasks=1
        Rack-local map tasks=2
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=16730
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=4673
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=16730
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=4673
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=16730
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=4673
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=17131520
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all reduce tasks=4785152
```

Comment: I'd be more concerned why the Python one was 2 to 3 times longer to operate. I'd say the input files were different

Comment: I used same input file for both the runs.